# Provide a way to review question asked by the users

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are many questions that are to do with user interface design at the conceptual stage. When suggestions are put forward, it is usually to help generate ideas, and then the user can try and apply the suggestions. I want to know if we can try and get the person who asks the question to show what the final design looks like so it makes the question more complete. This is so we can also get feedback on the design suggestion (i.e. what they actually ended up doing, or even better, what the resulting interface looks like) and get the whole picture rather than having the question hanging as incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people *do* come back and amend their question to say what it is they went with, but that is not that common. However I don't see that as a problem.

If a question has been given an answer and that answer is upvoted and / or accepted then the question *isn't* hanging as incomplete - the answer to the question has been given and therefore the problem has been solved.

While it might be interesting from a curiosity point of view to find out exactly what the poster did with the answer information, that isn't the point of this site. It's not a site for case-studies or specific individual solutions, it's a site for Questions and Answers. If you post a question and someone tells you *"you should do X to solve that"* and the poster accepts that answer then there isn't anything else we really need to know. They had a question, someone solved it and the answer they left is the solution.

Comment: Incomplete is probably not the best way to describe it, although it is a question that I see asked often enough with the questions I have participated in. Generally it is because not a lot of detail is provided in the initial question, and so even if an answer is accepted it is difficult to know the exact reason and also just what part of the answer they accepted/applied to the solution.

Comment: Well a question should detail the problem in enough detail that an answer can be left, otherwise how can people then answer it? If the question doesn't provide enough detail then you should comment against that question explaining to the poster that they need to provide more detail if they want useful answers. I think the problem is with the quality of the question, not with the lack of follow-up information.